# Gcov doesn't generate .gcno files on windows

Tags: c++, windows, code-coverage, gcov, nmake

I'm trying to generate code coverage using gcov.

When I'm compiling (with --coverage flag) on linux, I have no problems, but when I'm trying the same thing on windows, no .gcno files are generated... I have no errors, just nothing is generated.

I have absolutely no clue on what's happening and what do I need to do to generate those files.

Edit: It's a Qt project, we're using .pro to generate Makefiles. We're using MSVC 14.16.27023 to compile the project.

Some help would be really appreciated, I'm loosing my (few remaining) hairs on this one...

Edit2: Defined flags in one of the the makefiles :

`CXXFLAGS      = -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zc:__cplusplus /W3 --coverage -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\xxxxxxx.vc.pdb $(DEFINES)`

`LFLAGS        = /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT --coverage /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'"`

Comment: Showing makefile or equivalent might be useful. Also which compiler/environment on windows do you use?

Comment: I edited my post with the compiler. However, I'm not allowed to show any code/scripts/makefiles from the project... But the --coverage flag is present on the compilation lines, but nothing happend...

Comment: Create a minimal one from scratch. In the process, you might even find the issue/fix by yourself.

Comment: I don't use WIndows nor MSVC and am just surprised that MSVC should be using gcov, which is a GNU utility, and that the CLI option to use it is of the same format that for gcc, `--coverage`. Are you perfectly sure this is OK?

Comment: Here they write VS has an `/EnableCodeCoverage` command-line option,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2019   Have you tried this?